# Why is Kivy FocusBehavior applied to Buttons not working?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

In the kivy.FocusBehavior documentation (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.html), an example with a FocusButton(FocusBehavior, Button) is given. But using the tab key on Windows 10 to cycle between the buttons added to the GridLayout does not work. What is wrong in the code below ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors.focus import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class FocusButton(FocusBehavior, Button):
    def _on_focus(self, instance, value, *largs):
        print(self.text)

class FocusBehaviorGUI(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)

        self.cols = 4
        self.rows = 2
        
        for i in range(8):
            self.add_widget(FocusButton(text=str(i)))
        # clicking on a widget will activate focus, and tab can now be used
        # to cycle through

class FocusBehaviorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FocusBehaviorGUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FocusBehaviorApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working. try changing:

```
def _on_focus(self, instance, value, *largs):
```

to:

```
def on_focus(self, instance, value, *largs):
```